# Post order by selected tags

Tags: tags, order

Let's say you want to show posts tagged with tags : "HTML, CSS".

I want to order posts in tag archive in the following order:

Post tagged with only exact two tags - HTML,CSS
Post tagged with only exact two tags - HTML, CSS
Posts tagged with three tags - HTML, CSS, jQuery
Posts tagged with three tags - HTML, CSS, ZEND
Posts tagged with four tags - HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP
etc.

So first result/s should only output posts with only exact specified tags.
After there are no more posts tagged with only those two tags, output posts tagged those 2 tags + only one more tag. And so on.

What should I use? Two wpQueryPosts loops? Can it be done with only one loop?
How to sort by matched tags?

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Else it gets quickly _very_ opinionated. Just file an [edit] and add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of tags when a post is saved and store it as a meta key for the post. Now you can just add a sort by the value of the meta key to the tag page query.

Comment: We're on to something. I modified tag.php in twentythirteen. It sorts them as I wanted BUT seems like my query broke tag recognition. What I mean is it sorts them by number of tags, but completely ignoring what tags are selected. So it shows all posts with all tags and only sorts them by meta_value. How to fix this? I know there is tag argument for wpquery but how to include selected tags? $_GET[tags]? Will this even work with pretty permalinks? Anyways, I appreciate your help. Here's the pastebin of my tag.php http://pastebin.com/Rfcp7bT2

Comment: you don't populate the parameters from the parameters of the original query. If you still can't figure it out please make it a separate question

Comment: I used $tag = get_query_var('tag') and passed it to my custom wpQuery. Now it works like charm. Thank you @Mark